# c++ Vector efficiency

Tags: c++, performance, vector

> The standard requires that vector implementations can efficiently add elements at
>   run time. Because vectors grow efficiently, it is often unnecessary—and can result
>   in poorer performance—to define a vector of a specific size. The exception to this
>   rule is if all the elements actually need the same value. If differing element values are
>   needed, it is usually more efficient to define an empty vector and add elements as
>   the values we need to become known at run time.

Reading in C++ prime (C++ 11 edition). Can someone explain to me why does that happens to be the case. I mean imagine we need to add somewhere 1 million **different** numbers into the std::vector.
**Why is that if I push_back them into the vector which hasn't defined approximate size** **will be the more "efficient" way than defining the size**? I mean I have a vague understanding of vector size and capacity and I believe every time Vector exceeds its capacity all the elements are copied into the bigger size array (n * 2 or n * 1.5 somewhere the neighborhood)...

Comment: If the final size of the vector is known ahead of time, it is perfectly fine to call `reserve(n)` on the vector before populating it.  If the final size is not known, the guidance is to let the vector grow as it sees fit.

Comment: Watch from 45:45   https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661   std::vector beating std::list and std::map for 500,000 elements   Take away: You need to measure.

Comment: Presumably in contrast to over-allocating "just in case", it's saying that vector growth is fast enough you generally shouldn't worry.

Comment: Look if I think that the number amount will be at least 1 million. Should I define the vector's approximate size or let it grow?

Comment: Okay Richard, I will definitely watch it...

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple types such as ints, declaring a vector with the number of elements needed will likely be faster than using `push_back`, because the vector won't need to do any reallocations. However, with complex classes which have constructors, doing so will default-construct all the elements and then overwrite them, wasting time.

In both cases, the best solution would be to use `reserve` to allocate space for all the elements at once without constructing those elements. Then you can use `push_back` without worrying about reallocations.

Comment: So to put it simply, if I will have at least 1million of "Person" type instance which needs to be added into the vector is it more efficient to use vector.reserve(1e6)(By the way did I use "e" correctly? )?

Comment: Yes, compared to declaring the vector with 1 million default-constructed `Person` objects or using `push_back` without `reserve`. `1e6` is numerically correct, but it is a double value. It shouldn't cause problems here as doubles should be able to represent this exactly, but in general you shouldn't use floating point numbers when they aren't necessary.